# Anglia Ruskin University Harvard referencing for Latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I'm very new  to Latex. I'm trying to add the latest Anglia Ruskin referencing style to my document but I'm stuck on halfway. I managed to get most things correct like the reference style. My main problem is the citation style. What I need is something like this:

- bla bla bla (vgl. Author 2021) bla bla bla

The problem I have with the following setup is, that I get this output while using an \textcite

- bla bla bla Author (2021)

Can someone help me where I'm making a mistake or how I can declare a textcite like I want it?

My Setup:

````
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

% Layout
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=8cm}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-comp, giveninits, uniquename=init, maxbibnames=999,
  urldate=long,
  innamebeforetitle, articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

% 1.2
\DeclareDelimFormat*{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% 2.5
\DeclareDelimFormat{andothersdelim}{\addcomma\space}

% 2.7
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}

% 2.8
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother

% ignore 2.10 for the time being

% 4.1
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldAlias{biblistlabeldate}{biblabeldate}

% 4.3
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}

% 4.4
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

% as for the year of the chapterv vs year of the book in 4.4
% I have never seen such a distinction and in general I imagine
% it would be quite hard to find out the year of a chapter
% in a collection work since only the year of the collection is given
% I imagine that in practice you would almost always end up duplicating
% the year.

% 4.8 & 5.11
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom   = {available at},
  urlseen   = {accessed},
  bathesis  = {BA},
  mathesis  = {MA},
  phdthesis = {PhD},
}
\newcommand*{\mkbiburlangle}[1]{<#1>}
% or {<#1>}
% or {\ensuremath{\langle}#1\ensuremath{\rangle}}
% or {guilsinglleft#1\guilsingleright}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space \mkbiburlangle{\url{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibcpstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% 4.9
\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

% 4.12 :-(
% note that I used the new preferred resolver https://doi.org/
% instead of http://dx.doi.org/
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}


\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\title{Audioresponsive Shader (HLSL)}
\author{Roman Aebi}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Hauptsection}



\begin{enumerate}
\item Eine weitere Auflistung
\item Eine weitere Auflistung
\item Eine weitere Auflistung
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\section{Noch eine Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5, axis lines=middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, title={2D axis graph}]
        \addplot[color=red, dashed, mark=*]{x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\onecolumn
\lipsum[1]
\section{Die letzte Lection}
\lipsum[1]
\textcite{arzteblatt_virtual-reality_2021}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
    xmin=0,xmax=2.5*pi,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick={0,pi/2,pi ,3*pi/2,2*pi},
    xticklabels ={$0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3}{2}\pi$, $2\pi$},
    xticklabel style={anchor=south west},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,red]{sin(deg(x))}
    node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=\sin x$};
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,,blue]{cos(deg(x))}
    node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=\cos x$}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [colormap/cool]
        \addplot3[surf]{1+x^2-y^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\textcite{heckbert_fourier_1995}
\printbibliography
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your example isn't exactly minimal. You certainly don't need to include a plot in a question about `biblatex`. Why do you want `\textcite` to behave this way, when `\parencite` already gives you this (basic) format.  In author-year systems, `\textcite` gives you Author (Year) and `\parencite` gives you (Author, Year).

Comment: Your example is too long, but generally for citations in parentheses use `\parencite[vgl][]{key}`